# How can I reflect fixed width byte[] field information on a struct?

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection, struct, system.reflection

I am trying to find a way to with reflected field information for fields on structs.  My structs often contain fixed-width byte arrays.  When I encounter one of these arrays while iterating over the list of struct fields, I need to catch if a field is an array and handle the array differently than my other field types.  How can I do this?

As an example, here is a sample struct and the following method also articulates my problem?

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct MyStruct
{
     public int IntegerVal;
     public unsafe fixed byte MyByteBuff[20];
}


//Later in code...
public static void WorkWithStructs(Type t) //t will always be a struct
{
    foreach (var f in t.GetFields())
    {
        if (f.FieldType == typeof(int)
        { 
            //Do Int work
        } 
        else if (???)  //Test for a fixed-width byte array
        {
            // If MyStruct were passed to this method, this is where I 
            // would need to handle the MyByteBuff field.  Specifically, 
            // I need to discern the object type (in this case a byte) 
            // as well as the length in bytes.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be too surprised if you would find that these fixed fields cannot be treated the usual way with reflection. Anyway, your best bet is to debug the application, and look at `f` and its properties in the debugger.

Comment: I have.  I can get close to discerning something that looks to *possibly* be such a field, but I can't find all of the necessary pieces of information.  I've not used reflection much before this requirement.  Hopefully a 'guru' can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the presence of the `FixedBufferAttribute` custom attribute on your field types (found in the `CustomAttributes` collection of the type.

In your case, you be able to check for the presence of an attribute that matches the following:

```
[FixedBufferAttribute(typeof(Byte), 20)]
```

(adding the `FixedBufferAttribute` is done automatically - if you try to add it manually, you will get an error saying to use the `fixed` keyword instead).